# How can we use array elements as a counters in java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DemoArrayElement {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] freq = new int[7];

        for (int roll = 1; roll < 10; roll++) {
            ++freq[1 + rand.nextInt(6)];
        }
        System.out.println("FACE\tFREQUENCY");

        for (int face = 1; face < freq.length; face++) {
            System.out.println(face + "\t\t" + freq[face]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain me this `++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];` line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program simulates rolling a die 10 times. The array `freq` is used to count the frequencies each face value is rolled - the index represents the face value and the content the number of times it was rolled. So, e.g., `freq[3]` contains the number of times `3` was rolled.

Let's take a look at `++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];` and take it apart:

`rand.nextInt(6)` calls Java's random number generator (a `java.util.Random` instance) and asks it for a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 5 (inclusive). Adding 1 to it gives you a random face value form a die - a number between 1 and 6.

Accessing this index in the `freq` array (`freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)]`), as noted above, will return the number of times this face value was randomly encountered. Since we just encountered it again, this number is incremented (the `++` operator).

Answer (score 2):

`frec` is an array containing 7 numeric elements.

`++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];` means pre-increment a random element from an array.

---

Example: if the second element from the array is `5`:

`++freq[1];` will make it `6`.

Comment: Important to note that it will never touch the 0th element of `freq`, because `1+rand.nextInt(6)` generates a random number between 1 and 6.